# MongoDB aggregate $match stage with conditional query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to do a match stage in mongoDB aggregate, and in this match I want to check if a condition exists, use a custom query, and if not, use another custom query. The custom queries are nested fields.

after searching and reading documents , I write this code. But it has an error.

I use MongoDB v4.4 . only this version and cannot switch to other versions.

MongoError: FieldPath field names may not contain '.'.

```
{
  $match : {
    $expr : {
      $cond : {
        if: { $eq : [ 'type' , 'country'] },
        then: { 
          $and : [
            { 'countryState.status' : 'Confirmed' },
            { 'countryState.prop' : 'high' },          
          ]
        },
        else: {  },
      }
    }
  }
},
```

If the 'type' field, is equal to country, I want to use the custom query, and if not, only {} query.

I would appreciate anyone can help me, how to this match stage with conditional query.

Comment: I think you can simplify this. Get rid of $expr and $cond. Use $or instead

Comment: @user20042973  then how can I check the condition? I want only if the condition exist, use the query.

Comment: The point is there is nothing else to check if the condition isn't true. So when `type` is `'country'` you want to apply some additional constraints. But when the `type` is _not_ `'country'` then you don't want to filter it further. Added as an answer for consideration

Comment: @user20042973 You were right, thank you. it works very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for the query to return "this or that", so we should use `$or`. Borrowing the sample data from @cmgchess playground link, this query should logically do what you want I believe:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "type": "country",
          "countryState.status": "Confirmed",
          "countryState.prop": "high"
        },
        {
          "type": {
            $ne: "country"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TQgH5x15WLO)